# Copy data from one table to another table using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query to copy data from one table `(CUSTOMER_TABLE with 130 columns)` to another table `(FAIL_CUSTOMER_TABLE with 132 columns)` in `sql server`.

`FAIL_CUSTOMER_TABLE` has two extra columns but both have `default` values declared.

I am getting below exception for the below query. Can any one help me in writing the query with out listing all 130 columns in the query.

```
INSERT into dbo.FAIL_CUSTOMER_TABLE
select *,'N' AS 'FIXED', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS 'DATE' 
from dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE 
where LTRIM(RTRIM(CustNumber)) !='' 
and Processed = 'N' 
order by ROWID asc 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.XML_FAIL_RECORDS OFF
```

Error message

> explicit value for the identity column in table
>   'dbo.FAIL_CUSTOMER_TABLE' can only be specified when a column list is
>   used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Answer (score 2):

You missed to add `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.XML_FAIL_RECORDS ON`  before the `insert`

Also you need to mention `column list` while setting `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.XML_FAIL_RECORDS ON --Missed in your query

INSERT into dbo.FAIL_CUSTOMER_TABLE(Identity_Col,col1,col2...)
select Identity_Col,col1,col2,....,'N' AS 'FIXED', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS 'DATE' 
from dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE 
where LTRIM(RTRIM(CustNumber)) !='' 
and Processed = 'N' 
order by ROWID asc 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.XML_FAIL_RECORDS OFF
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I have any other options to write the query with out mentioning the column names as any how they are default values. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @newuser -No you need to explicitly mention the column list. or you can generate the column list using `information_schema.column` with `dynamic query`